# start-service run as administrator

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want start some services with start-service command .These services start only with administrator privilege. I use this command in ps1 file and run it in windows scheduler. the services cant start. I log on the task with my user has administrator role but It can start.

```
start-service Netlogon
```

has error :

erroe : Start-Service : Service 'Netlogon (Netlogon)' cannot be started due
   to the following error: Cannot open Netlogon service on computer '.'.
   At line:1 char:1
   + Start-Service Netlogon
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError:
   (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
     ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
    CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: Just to verify, when you log on as administrator, you _can_ or _can't_ start it? If you can run it as administrator directly, then it'll just be a matter of making sure the scheduled task is running with admin credentials...but I'm betting you meant to write "can't". In which case, I'd have to do more research...

Comment: you can use `-Credential` and pass your admin credential if you aren't logged in as admin.

Comment: I can't log in with administrator users or run powershell as administrator. start-service doesn't have -credential switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

net start Netlogon

Though it is a batch command but worked in Powershell as well. I run as local account not required to run PS as administrator